# Updatepanel in ascx refreshing the whole control

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, sitecore, sitecore7

I've got a sitecore proejct, in which I have prepared a sub-layout in the form of an ascx User Control. I need to set up cascading drop downs in this user control, and based on what I found an UpdatePanel is the way to go. The problem is that the UpdatePanel seems to be refreshing the whole control, which I don't think is the correct behaviour.

I understand there are some similar questions on SO, but none of the solutions worked for me. I'm also beginning to suspect that this may be a Sitecore specific issue.

Here is a code sample of the user control:

```html
    <p><%= MyItem.Text %>" /></p>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="LocationFilterUpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDL1_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">

        </asp:DropDownList>


        <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL2"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDL2_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">

        </asp:DropDownList>

    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And the Code Behind:

```cs
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).IsInAsyncPostBack)
        {
            var context = new SitecoreContext();
            //Get Model from Sitecore

            DDL1.DataSource = Model.Data;
            DDL1.DataValueField = "Id";
            DDL1.DataTextField = "Name";
            DDL1.DataBind();
        }

    }

    protected void DDL1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var context = new SitecoreContext();
        //Get Model from Sitecore

        DDL2.DataSource = Model.Data;
        DDL2.DataValueField = "Id";
        DDL2.DataTextField = "Name";
        DDL2.DataBind();
    }

    protected void DDL2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

The page loads fine, but (when debugging) changing the DDL1's index it will show a Null exception in MyItem.Text. This is outside the control panel. Note: I have also added a script manager.

There are plenty of things I've tried. Setting different update modes, updated the AjaxToolkit in my solution by executing Install-Package AjaxControlToolkit from the Package Manager Console... but the behaviour remains the same.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the databinding for DDL1 to the `OnInit`, rather than the `Page_Load`.
And don't include the `if` statement in there, just do the databind.
After the `OnInit` the selected values will be correctly set and you will be able to access the DDL1's options in the other event handlers.

Comment: Thank you. It worked.

I would appreciate if you know why it works in the OnInit and not the Page_Load though? I built a separate project to try it out and (non-sitecore) and it's working fine if I leave that code in the page load?

Comment: It works because during OnInit, the viewstate values have not been loaded yet. So you have the chance to populate the dropdownlist with values. Then in between OnInit and Page_Load, the PreLoad event is fired during which the viewstate is loaded and applied to the controls (e.g. it sets the selected index). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx for all details.

Comment: That's indeed what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You  have asp:DropDownList control with an AutoPostBack set to true.

Remove the AutoPostBack=true from the Dropdownlist control  and set an Async trigger for your UpdatePanel, set to the Dropdownlist and its eventname="SelectedIndexChanged"

This is a know issue, and you find a lot of documentation about it.

Comment: That causes the event not to trigger at all.

I understand that if the DropDownList is inside the control, the Triggers are not required.

If I do that, the DropDownList doesn't fire the event.

I have in fact tried this in a separate project and it worked fine. I suspect Sitecore 7 (or one of the modules installed in it) is breaking functionality of the update panel.